# Problem facing error 401 unauthorized in angular

Tags: angular

I am having a problem regarding Angular. I am trying to call the "List" endpoint from the BE, but I am stuck getting the already mentioned error.
Here is my code:
**auth.interceptor.ts**

```
import {
  HttpHandler,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
} from '@angular/common/http';

const AUTH_KEY = 'auth';

export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    const token = localStorage.getItem(AUTH_KEY);
    if (token) {
      const authReq = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer' + token),
      });
      return next.handle(authReq);
    }
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

**access-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Renderer2, ViewChild, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AccessClient, AccessLog } from '../services/api.service';
import { AppStateService } from '../services/app-state.service';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-access-list',
  templateUrl: './access-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./access-list.component.scss'],
})
export class AccessListComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  TRANSACTION_HEIGHT = 50;

  @ViewChild('scrollContainer') scrollContainer!: ElementRef;
  state = inject(AppStateService);
  accessClient = inject(AccessClient);
  accesses: AccessLog[] = [];
  pagesize = 10;
  currentPage = 1;
  lastPage = false;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private authService: AuthService) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.addScrollListener();
  }

  addScrollListener() {
    this.renderer.listen(
      this.scrollContainer.nativeElement,
      'scroll',
      (event: Event) => {
        if (this.isAtTopOfDiv(event)) {
          this.loadAccesses();
        }
      }
    );
  }

  isAtTopOfDiv(event: Event) {
    const target = event.target as HTMLElement;
    return target.scrollTop === 0;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.state.acesses$.subscribe((access) => {
      this.accesses = access;
    });
  }

  loadAccesses() {
    if (this.lastPage) {
      return;
    }

    this.accessClient
      .list(this.state.nukiId, this.currentPage + 1)
      .subscribe((accesses) => {
        if (accesses.length == 0) {
          this.lastPage = true;
          return;
        }
        this.accesses = [...this.accesses, ...accesses];
        this.currentPage++;
        var container = this.scrollContainer.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
        container.scrollTo({
          top: accesses.length * this.TRANSACTION_HEIGHT,
          behavior: 'smooth',
        });
      });
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AuthenticationComponent } from './authentication/authentication.component';
import { AccessListComponent } from './access-list/access-list.component';
import { OpenDoorButtonComponent } from './open-door-button/open-door-button.component';
import { CreditTotalComponent } from './credit-total/credit-total.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { AccessPageComponent } from './access-page/access-page.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';
import { API_BASE_URL } from './services/api.service';
import { ErrorInterceptor } from './interceptor/error.interceptor';
import { ShowNukiIdComponent } from './show-nuki-id/show-nuki-id.component';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
import { AuthInterceptor } from './interceptor/auth.interceptor';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AuthenticationComponent,
    AccessListComponent,
    OpenDoorButtonComponent,
    CreditTotalComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    AccessPageComponent,
    ShowNukiIdComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatIconModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    {
      provide: API_BASE_URL,
      useValue: environment.baseUrl,
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: ErrorInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, map } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthenticationClient, User } from './api.service';

const AUTH_KEY = 'auth';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private currentUSerSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User | null>(null);

  constructor(private authenticationClient: AuthenticationClient) {}

  public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    if (this.currentUSerSubject.value != null) {
      return true;
    }

    const token = localStorage.getItem(AUTH_KEY);
    if (token != null) {
      const response = JSON.parse(token);
      this.currentUSerSubject.next(response.user!);
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  public logout(): void {
    localStorage.removeItem(AUTH_KEY);
    this.currentUSerSubject.next(null);
  }

  public getToken(): string | null {
    const response = localStorage.getItem(AUTH_KEY);
    if (response == null) {
      return null;
    }

    return JSON.parse(response).access_token;
  }

  public login(nukiId: number, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authenticationClient
      .login({ nukiId: nukiId, password: password })
      .pipe(
        map((result) => {
          if (!result.access_token) {
            return false;
          }

          localStorage.setItem(AUTH_KEY, JSON.stringify(result));
          this.currentUSerSubject.next(result.user!);
          return true;
        })
      );
  }

  public get user$(): Observable<User | null> {
    return this.currentUSerSubject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

I expect the backend to return the response instead of error 401.

Comment: There is a missing space between Bearer and token. Replace this line of code with this: `headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token),`

Comment: It's not working

Comment: Did you check the request in the browser console to see if and how the authorization header is set?

Comment: I did not and I can see that the request correctly sends the token but the response says "Www-Authenticate:
Bearer error="invalid_token". We probably have a problem with the Backend

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem by checking the "Network" section when inspecting my web-page. The problem was:

- I was trying to send to the backend a token that was emebedded in a JSON object

I fixed the problem with the following code line:

```
      const accessToken = JSON.parse(token).access_token;
```